# "Undefined index error" when reading a json output from a url using fromJSON in R while reading the same data from a text file works

Tags: php, r, json, jsonlite

I am using R. Consider this url with a query string.

```
url_bbmp <- "http://accounts.bbmpgov.in/PublicView/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadPaymentGridData&pCriteria=&pDateFrom=01-Jan-1900&pDateTo=01-Jan-1900&pDateType=pDF&pOrderBy=-1&pFinancialYearID=-1&pBudgetHeadID=-1&pDDOIDs=&pWardIDs=&pDateFilterYN=false&pWardID=174&filterscount=0&groupscount=0&pagenum=0&pagesize=2&recordstartindex=0&recordendindex=2&_=1614505598778#"
```

If you paste the url on a browser you see a large output of seemingly normal json text.

But if you try reading the json text using

```
fromJSON(url_bbmp)
```

It spits an error:

> $rError
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjngn.jpg) "Undefined index: dgLanguage"

This looks like a PHP error.

However, there is no problem in the json text because if you copy paste the json text from the browser window on to a text file (say `raw_publicview.txt`)  and read the text file using the following r command on the console,

```
jsonlite::read_json("raw_publicview.txt") %>% length()
```

Bingo ! The above runs successfully with output:

> #### [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjngn.jpg) 189

Even this works:

```
fromJSON(readLines("raw_publicview.txt",warn = F)) %>% as.data.frame %>% nrow()
```

> #### [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjngn.jpg) 189

My question is why is `fromJSON` not able to read from the URL directly? And why this peculiar error?
Update:
Adding a screen grab from my browser window with same url.
[image]

Comment: When I paste the URL into my browser, I don't get "a large output of seemingly normal json text", but instead get "{"rError":"Undefined index: dgLanguage"}"

Comment: Strange, @mhovd, because I just tried again and the output is indeed coming as json text. Could you check if the copy pasting had any problem? I use chrome browser. I will try to add a pic of  the browser window.

Comment: I am getting the same error, `{"rError":"Undefined index: dgLanguage"}` on both Chrome and Edge, with and without private browsing. Are there any APIs you could query for the information instead?

Comment: There are no APIs. This is a govt site. BTW I am also now getting the same error (tested on Firefox as well as Chrome Incognito window).  So it seems my chrome browser was reading this from cache. Let me investigate a bit more. Thanks for trying it out.

Comment: Apparently I think this is not an R problem. The website doesn't return data after a certain time gap, perhaps an expiry happens. So we can close this question.